# Is it possible to perform a bitwise group function in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

How to perform bitwise OR on hive query similar to mysql.
For example in mysql we perform bitwise or as :

`SELECT user_name, BIT_OR(file_permission) FROM user_permission GROUP BY user_name`

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Bitwise or operator in hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ArithmeticOperators):

> A | B
>
> Operand types: All number types
>
> Gives the result of bitwise OR of A and B. The type of the result is the same as the common parent(in the type hierarchy) of the types of the operands.

However, from your code sample it seems that you need an aggregate Bitwise or function (UDAF). Such aggregate function does not readily exist in hive. You'll have to implement a custom UDAF.

Another option that is less efficient but simpler: you can use `collect_list` and implement a simple UDF that performs bitwise or on all elements of an array.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I ended up implementing my own UDF to perform this operation.